# Using seaborn and contourf, how can I plot gridlines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Using the following code, the first contour plot has grid lines. For the second plot, I have imported seaborn, but the grid lines don't show up. What do I need to add to make the grid lines show on the second plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dx=0.05
x=np.arange(0,5+dx,dx)
y=x
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.sin(X)**10+np.cos(10+Y*Y)*np.cos(X)

nbins=10
levels=mpl.ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins).tick_values(Z.min(),Z.max())

plt.figure()
plt.contourf(x,y,Z,levels=levels)
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid('on')

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_context("notebook")
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

plt.figure()
plt.contourf(x,y,Z,levels=levels)
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to change either the `axes.axisbelow` rc parameter or the zorder of the contourf plot. So you could do

```
sns.set(context="notebook", style="whitegrid",
        rc={"axes.axisbelow": False})
```

When you set up the style or

```
plt.contourf(x, y, Z, levels=levels, zorder=0)
```

When you draw the plot.

Comment: Thank you. By way of explanation, is it that seaborn sets the parameters so that the grid is drawn below the solid contour plot, so the grid lines are obscured. "axes.axisbelow": False sets the axes and grid lines to plot on top of the figure and zorder=0 sets the contour plot to plot first, below the axes and grid lines. Is that right?

Comment: Right, the seaborn grid is drawn below all data elements, which looks better for most kinds of plots but as you found, doesn't work well in the case of an image-like plot.